# Use localStorage.setItem to keep same show/hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage, show-hide

I work with a function in my main page. All works fine, I just want to know how to  keep the select language in a page when i click on a link and go in another page.

For example id="en" is the language by default, but if I want to use id="fr" in my main page, and click on link who will send me in another page. I will come back to id="en". So to keep the same language how can I use this function :

```
localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);
currentlanguage= localStorage.getItem("language");
```

Here is the jsfiddle of the function that I use to switch language:

https://jsfiddle.net/kodjoe/chvw181j/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.lan').hide();
  $('.en').show();
});

$('.button').click(function(event) {
  $('.lan').hide();
  var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
  var setActiveLanguage = "." + selectedLanguage;
  $(setActiveLanguage).show();

localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage);
currentlanguage= localStorage.getItem("language"); 
});
```

```css
.button {
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0px 30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="button" id="en">EN</a>
<a class="button" id="fr">FR</a>
<a class="button" id="de">DE</a>


<div class="lan en">1</div>
<div class="lan fr">2</div>
<div class="lan de">3</div>
<div class="lan en">4</div>
<div class="lan fr">5</div>
<div class="lan de">6</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't be hard to figure out ... set inside event handler, get on page load.

Comment: @charlietfl I don't really know if it's like that, and I will need to use it in other pages ?

Comment: for setting yes. But you want to `get` on page load so you know what you hide/show then

Comment: When I click on "run code snippet" 
I've a message error ? and which part of code I need to put in other pages  ?

Comment: @coolio83000 Check my answer that will help you to set the localStorage item. 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39676980/6608101

Comment: i have done it already check the answer!

Comment: @SifatulIslam Man see the difference between your code and mine, the number of lines to achieve the same functionality :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

firstly store your value

```
$('.button').click(function(event) {
  $('.lan').hide();
  var selectedLanguage = $(this).attr('id');
  var setActiveLanguage = "." + selectedLanguage;
  $(setActiveLanguage).show();

localStorage.setItem("language", selectedLanguage); //storing under the key of language

});
```

then fetch the value on ready in your `.ready` function

```
var langStored = localStorage.getItem("language");
```

if no values is stored it will return `null`.

So put conditions there what you want to do when you get `langStored` and when you get `null`

take a peek at: [codepen](http://codepen.io/sifii2013/pen/qaAVLo)

Answer (score 0):

Set / Get the localStorage item.

```
localStorage.setItem('selectedLang', $(this).attr('id'));

localStorage.getItem('selectedLang');
```

Documentation : [HTML5 Web Storage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Code for your example

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lan').hide();
    var classSel = localStorage.getItem('selectedLang') ? localStorage.getItem('selectedLang') :  'en';
    //Get the value from localStorage and show that class only
    $('.'+classSel).show();

    $('.button').click(function(event) {
        $('.lan').hide();
        $("." + $(this).attr('id')).show();
        //Set the localStorage value
        localStorage.setItem('selectedLang', $(this).attr('id'));
    });
});
```

Comment: ok I need to add your code in my main page, but I've to put in others page who run the same function ?

Comment: It's better to create a one common js file, that will load full code of javascript as mentioned, that will work if the HTML is available for button, or it will show the previously selected value from localstorage, you get my point ?