# how add localStorage to show and hide divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

how add localStorage to show/hide divs? Before asking this question I have see this article [Use localStorage.setItem to keep same show/hide divs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39676522/use-localstorage-setitem-to-keep-same-show-hide-divs) but that does not help me, still i can't do it by my self, so i need help! thanks.
my code

```
$(function() {
  $("#mesfavgame").css("display", "none");
  $(".AvGamesCheckBox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#mesfavgame").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#mesfavgame").show();
    }
  });
});
```

if checkbox `.AvGamesCheckBox` is checked, localStorage hide message `id="mesfavgame"`, if checkbox `.AvGamesCheckBox` is unchecked localStorage show message `id="mesfavgame"`

```
<div id="favorite">
  <div id="mesfavgame"> You don't have any favorite game </div>   
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the relevant HTML as well...

Comment: Thanks, I have add the html on my question, thanks again

Comment: Could you please fix your grammar as it is very unclear what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: if checkbox `.AvGamesCheckBox` is checked, localStorage hide message `id="mesfavgame"`, if checkbox `.AvGamesCheckBox` is unchecked localStorage show message `id="mesfavgame"` thanks for your help.

Comment: (offtopic) @Leo, regarding your recent deleted question: See this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m0nhgsfb/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

**HTML:**

```
<input type="checkbox" class="AvGamesCheckBox">
<div id="favorite">
  <div id="mesfavgame"> You don't have any favorite game </div>   
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  var status = localStorage.getItem('chkStatus');
  if(status == 'true'){
    $("#mesfavgame").css("display", "none");
    $(".AvGamesCheckBox").attr('checked', true)
  }
  else{
    $("#mesfavgame").css("display", "block");
    $(".AvGamesCheckBox").attr('checked', false)
  }
  $(".AvGamesCheckBox").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
      $("#mesfavgame").hide();
    }
    else {
      $("#mesfavgame").show();
    }
    localStorage.setItem("chkStatus", this.checked);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Local storage is easy enough to use.
What you should do, is keep a variable of all the changes made in the page from the default.
For example, let's say you got a div in the page that the user can show or hide:

```
#header-div
```

Which is hidden at the beginning.
You simply add it to an array when it is open and remove it when it is closed.
And then you save it to local storage

```
openedDivs= [];
$(".clickable-header").click(function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        $("#header-div").hide();
        openedDivs= openedDivs.filter(function(value) { return value !== "header-div" });
        localStorage.setItem("openedDivs", openedDivs);
    }
    else {
        $("#header-div").show();
        openedDivs.push("openedArray");
        localStorage.setItem("openedDivs", openedDivs);
    }
});
```

And then, simply on page load, get the variable from the storage using

```
localStorage.getItem("openedDivs")
```

And use it to apply it to your document.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
$("#mesfavgame").css("display", "none");
$(".AvGamesCheckBox").click(function() {
        if (this.checked && localStorage.getItem("isChecked") != null && localStorage.getItem("isChecked") == "true") {
            $("#mesfavgame").hide();
            localStorage.setItem("isChecked", "false")
        }
        else {
            $("#mesfavgame").show();
            localStorage.setItem("isChecked", "true");
        }
    });
});
```